# Why Error -26499: Internal Error on 2nd iteration onwards in LR?

Tags: loadrunner

Got a script which runs the first iteration just fine but after that before the next iteration starts, it throws following error before the action block starts. Looks like its trying **close some connections and failing** but why this behaviour? is there **any work around** for this? Attached the logs

- LR Version: 12.53 Build 1203
- OS: Windows 7
- Protocol used: Web HTTP/HTML
- Application - Sitecore/.NET/Janrain Authentication

Logs with advance trace looks like below. I'd like to emphasise on the line below.

```
Javascript calling stack is empty [MsgId: MMSG-26000]
```

This error doesn't impact the iteration since its happening outside a transaction and also before Action starts. It looks like a its a call made before starting Action block.

[image]

Let me know if any more info is required.

Comment: Protocol/Virtual User Type involved?

Comment: Something to note: Fiilter out the calls to third parties unless you have their permission and coordination on a performance test basis (ref GoogleAPIS.com)

Comment: Added the necessary info. I have the permission to hit those apis using a specific agreed header. Thanks for that info.

Comment: Was this issue resolved? If not, I'll be happy to help.

Comment: Thanks, I have removed calls to external (3rd party) APIs altogether by adding them in exception, I am yet to run this in Load Testing env. I'll update this post once that is done.